# Find part of the text in DOM by css-selector or xpath

Tags: css-selectors

Can you help me to find css selector or xpath. How I can find number two in this DOM. But I should find it only by index.

I can find this element by this:

```
label[class*='filter-item'] .o-flex__element
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on the element as displayed on your screen in Chrome, click `inspect` and you'll get the window below which shows the path to the element selected. You may need to manually navigate down a little but this works fairly well for a starting point

[image]